# How is it proved that S is dense in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

This question is from [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Apostol/ch1.pdf). The question is:

[image]

[image]

But, I can't understand how is it proved that S is dense in $\mathbb R$. I also can't understand how "dense in $\mathbb R$" and "dense in $[0,1]$ modulus $1$"are equivalent.

Please explain how I can get it. Thank you.

Comment: What definition of "dense" are you using?

Comment: There is no definition in the quoted page.

Comment: I'm asking what your definition of the term is. Do you know what it means for a set to be dense in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I asked the definition of dense on this site yesterday: [SEE THIS](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498290/dense-in-mathbbr-and-dense-in-0-1-modulus-1) Are these def.s OK?

Comment: They're fine. But since you're asking us to explain why $S$ is dense, you should make it clear which definition you are using. Generally you use the definition that makes the most sense to you.

Comment: Please elaborate more. Please say what should I do? I am new to analysis and am stuck.

Comment: I think these things relate to analytical number theory. If you want to self study elementary analysis from scratch use the book by Bartle, spivak, ross, etc.

Comment: Please someone help for this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, note that your set $S$ is periodic since if $x\in S$ with $x=ar+b$ then $x+k$ for any integer $k$ is also ($x+k=ar+(b+k)$).

That would explain why $S$ being dense modulo $1$ is the same as being dense in$\mathbb{R}$, suffices to focus on $[0,1]$.

As for what is being shown, the conclusion of your proof is that any real $x$ can be approximated by points of $S$ with arbitrarily small error (how I think about density). Specifically, it is shown that for any real $x$ and arbitrary $\delta>0$ there is a point $ s'\in S$ with $|s'-x|<\delta$. ($s'=sL$ in the proof)