# Is $(1,2)$ dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I am studying Real Analysis. Trying to understand the concepts.

Dense Sets : A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is said to be dense in $\mathbb{R}$ if $\bar{S}=\mathbb{R}$, i.e. the set of all limit points of $S$ is the same as $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, $S=(1,2)$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Is it dense ? For that we have to find the set of limit points of $S$.

What is a limit point ? A point $x$ is a limit point of set $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point $p\in S$ with $p\neq x$. Now, we have to define a neighbourhood.

A neighbourhood of a point is a set of points containing that point where one can move some amount away from that point without leaving the set.

So, a point $3$ has no neighbourhood in $S$. So, its not a limit point of $S$. Hence, $\bar{S}\neq \mathbb{R}$. Hence, $S$ is not dense ?

If the above is correct, sets like $[1,2],(0,n),...$ are NOT dense as well.

I need help to confirm if I understood the concepts here. Please advise.

Thanks.

EDIT: I found a similar question [dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and dense in $[0,1]$ modulus $1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498290/dense-in-mathbbr-and-dense-in-0-1-modulus-1)

I think this also suggests that $(1,2)$ is not dense in $\mathbb{R}$. But I don't want to jump to wrong conclusions.

Comment: Looks ok to me. The closure of $(1,2)$ is $[1,2]$ which is not the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, no bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is $4$ a limit point of $(1,2)$ ? now, since the open set $(3,5)$ contains $4$ and does not intersect $(1,2)$. We conclude $(1,2)$ is not a dense set, since $3$ is not a limit point of $(1,2)$.